# Client with two servers

Tags: server, client

I'm a NEW Android developer. I'm developing a client-server app. I'm using free [online host](http://www.000webhost.com) for my PHP & mySQL. My app will involve with data & images (both upload & download).

Since I'm using free hosting service, there are limitations (namely storage). I'm thinking of using two separate free hosts. One for the data and one for the images. I understand that I'll need to get data from one host and images from another. There will be multiple POSTs & GETs to complete a process. My images are stored on the server as actual images (not BLOB). I'll have to make HTTP post & get the images anyway once the links are provided/retrieved from the first post.

Do you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: It's fine, just use AJAX to the different pages as long as you have CORS access. Free hosting is usually always a bad idea, though.

Comment: I don't know AJAX and/or CORS.

Comment: Prepare for a steep learning curve.

Comment: Without AJAX & CORS. Do you still think it's a good idea for using two servers at the same time?

Comment: That depends if you're using Node, or PHP or something else on the Server Side. I don't think it would be faster in PHP because each result depends on the last one, while Node is non-blocking, so more servers could be faster.

Comment: They're all PHP on the server side. My first POST is to get all the file names. From the names, I'll POST back to get the actual images. [The images are NOT stored as BLOB.]